# Hypothetical incomplete type error: object versus pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, incomplete-type

In a hypothetical situation I have two classes A, and B.

I forward declare both A and B in the beginning of this header file:

```
class A;
class B;
```

Later I define class B, and define it as such:

```
class B
{
public:
A aInstance;
}
```

Essentially creating an object of type A called aInstance in class B.

This returns an incomplete type error, however,

```
class B
{
public:
A* aInstance;
}
```

does not.

What exactly about declaring the object bInstance as a pointer resolves this error? I'm mostly looking for an explanation to help me understand pointers better, because my understanding of them currently is not very rigorous.

Thanks

Comment: Whoops, sorry that was a lot of typos

Comment: what are "hypothetical classes" ?

Comment: This is a hypothetical situation: neither class A or class B actually exist in my code but I've run into an essentially identical issue in the same context, so I'm naming two hypotheticals, in this case, two classes, which are simplified from my code to help me boil down why this error is occuring

Comment: thats confusing, you have example code with them, so they do exist in your example code :)

Comment: fwiw, code you post here is rarely the same code you are working on and where the actual problem is. That is what a [mcve] is for: Only code relevant for the question, nothing else. I wouldn't call that hypothetical, but I understand what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, one thing the compiler knows from a class definition is the size of an instance of that class. Here, the compiler has all it needs to know because the size of a pointer does not depend on what it points to:

```
struct B {
    A* aInstance;
};
```

The size of `B` is the size of a pointer plus potentially padding. However, here:

```
struct B {
    A aInstance;
};
```

The size of `B` is the size of an instance of `A` and to know that the definition of `A`  is needed.

Comment: Thank you, so if I had defined A (with a constructor) prior to defining B, would the second instance (the non-pointer A aInstance) work?

Comment: @Dan yes that should be fine. "incomplete type" means that it is not defined yet, if you define it then it is not an incomplete type anymore